# SAXParseException for perfect XML tag

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, saxparser, nodelist

I am trying to parse an XML tag and in the process I received SAXParseException for a tag which is perfectly fine.

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://www.salesforce.com" id="theLink">www.salesforce.com</apex:outputLink>
```

I am parsing that tag with

`NodeList outputLink = document.getElementsByTagName("apex:outputLink");`

and received error

WARNING: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Public/pages/Page6.page; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 52; Element type "apex:outputLink" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Why am I receiving this error when my XML tag is totally okay. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Check and be sure the quotes are normal quotes and not left and/or right quotes.

Comment: I am using double quotes to hold values and so there is no possibility of left/right tags.

Comment: It's reporting an error on line 8. The tag you've shown us looks OK. But what's in the rest of the file?

Comment: Also, check that the spaces are not something special, like non-breaking spaces.

Comment: That error normally means I could read the <apex:outputLink open tag but something is wrong between that and the end of the tag ... >. It can happen if your system is using " and ” which are different, or as @MichaelKay suggests the spaces are not spaces but something like a non-breaking space. Position 52 would lead me to believe that the space or the quote after salesforce.com is the culprit.

Comment: I removed "id="theLink" from my tag and again added "id="theLink" to my tag back and gave run again and this time my pgm got successed. I just did, cut and paste and the exception went. I am not able figure out what went wrong before and how the exception went after the cut paste.